# export mysql db file in localhost by using html button

Tags: php

this is code but this is the error after comiling the code

```
<?php

//ENTER THE RELEVANT INFO BELOW
$mysqlDatabaseName ='school';
$mysqlUserName ='root';
$mysqlPassword ='';
$mysqlExportPath ='sqlbackups/chooseFilenameForBackup.sql';

//DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
$mysqlHostName ='localhost';
//Export the database and output the status to the page
$command='mysqldump -u' .$mysqlUserName .' -S /kunden/tmp/mysql5.sock -p' .$mysqlPassword .' ' .$mysqlDatabaseName .' > ~/' .$mysqlExportPath;
exec($command,$output=array(),$worked);
switch($worked){
    case 0:
        echo 'Database <b>' .$mysqlDatabaseName .'</b> successfully exported to <b>~/' .$mysqlExportPath .'</b>';
        break;
    case 1:
        echo 'There was a warning during the export of <b>' .$mysqlDatabaseName .'</b> to <b>~/' .$mysqlExportPath .'</b>';
        break;
    case 2:
        echo 'There was an error during export. Please check your values:<br/><br/><table><tr><td>MySQL Database Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlDatabaseName .'</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL User Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlUserName .'</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL Password:</td><td><b>NOTSHOWN</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL Host Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlHostName .'</b></td></tr></table>';
        break;
}

?>
```

this is the error
"There was a warning during the export of school to ~/sqlbackups/chooseFilenameForBackup.sql"

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: What var_dump($output) shows?

Comment: Is mysqldump in your system path(accessible everywhere on the command line?)

Comment: <form id="formacdemic" action="backup_hdl.php" method="post" class="uiform">
    
  
<input id="save1" class="btn btn-primary" value="get backup" name="save" type="submit">      
</form> this is the page where i go to first page

Comment: check first your mysqldump command on the command line. it appears that it is not returning 0 or success.